# What effect would a sperm containing XX have on a ovum and fetus?

Tags: genetics, birth, obstetrics

So this is just a random thought I had, while writing a story, but
I assume this is likely impossible currently, and likely in the far future aswell, but let's assume a scenario where the body that the sperm came from, was XX, instead of XY. Let's just assume through science, there were no other issues related to a different chromosome. (Maybe the organ was printed)
From what I understand, the sperm determines whether the resulting fetus is XX or XY, based on whether it carries X or Y from its creation in the original body.

Would a sperm producing body that has no Y, only XX (So no XXY or XYY), then essentially be incapable of producing XY children, with a XX ovum producing body?

Would there be other potential issues for the mother or the fetus/child?

I imagine with organ printing not being a impossible feat(at this level, and not yet anyway), this could be a hypothetical scenario for a FtM transgender in the future aswell, but mostly I was just curious on the conception of it.

TLDR: A XX sperm (whether possible or not), and a XX ovum, would only be able to create a XX fetus, and never a XY, yes?

Comment: Note that the Y chromosome contains several genes that are necessary for sperm production/maturation.

Comment: As @BryanKrause pointed out, XX males are sterile, so the scenario is impossible. Since you're writing fiction you can make it work however you want, but it makes your question unanswerable on a science-based forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, neglecting anything but the pure genetics' basics, yes, the XX mother will in any case transfer her X chromosome, just like the assumed "XX father", so the only possible genotype for the child is XX.

Comment: Actually, the genotype for this child is "XXX", also known as Triple X syndrome

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza in case an error occurs (e.g. nondisjunction) one would observe different genetic disorders (like the Trisomy X you mentioned), but this is not necessarily the case

Comment: That's true. I read "XX sperm" and assumed nondisjunction. If we're talking about a XX individual then the genotype can be XX or XXX.